# Rails - passenger RubyApps disappeared on a previously working Ubuntu/apache system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, passenger-apache

Passenger apps have stopped and will not restart. I am no longer able to restart my Rails apps via capistrano or passenger-config. The server was previously set up and working fine. I think the problem was introduced after an apt update and reboot.

```
01 passenger-config restart-app /var/www/inventory/development --ignore-app-not-running
01 There are no Phusion Passenger(R)-served applications running whose paths begin with '/var/www/inventory/development'.
```

Apache and passenger are running, but there are no Passenger RubyApps and no App groups listed.

```
# passenger-status
Version : 6.0.11
Date    : 2021-10-28 23:26:15 +0000
Instance: PDzzKrq3 (Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.11)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 0
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
# passenger-memory-stats
Version: 6.0.11
Date   : 2021-10-28 23:06:38 +0000

--------- Apache processes ---------
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------------
1025  1     429.2 MB  1.8 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1072  1025  431.5 MB  0.2 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1073  1025  431.5 MB  0.2 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1074  1025  431.5 MB  0.3 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1075  1025  431.5 MB  0.2 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1076  1025  431.5 MB  0.2 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
3833  1025  431.5 MB  0.2 MB   /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
### Processes: 7
### Total private dirty RSS: 3.23 MB


-------- Nginx processes --------

### Processes: 0
### Total private dirty RSS: 0.00 MB


---- Passenger processes -----
PID   VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------
1028  390.4 MB  2.8 MB   Passenger watchdog
1031  947.0 MB  3.9 MB   Passenger core
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 6.64 MB
```

How do I re-initialize these missing passenger applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug or incompatibility with passenger 6.0.11. I downgraded back to 6.0.10 and it started working again. You can follow the issue on the [passenger github](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2393).